# How to change line spacing when creating a RichEdit using winapi in C?

Tags: c, winapi, line-spacing

The line spacing cannot be changed with the source code below.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to create the `LSpaceA()` and `LSpaceB()` functions in the code below to change the line spacing.

Also, is the line `LoadLibrary("riched20.dll")` needed?

This is a slightly modified code obtained from a question on ChatGPT.
Compiled in DevC++.

When compiling in Visual Studio, various errors related to `strcat` and `sprintf` occur, so I have no choice but to test in DevC++.

Originally, I was looking for a way to change line spacing without using RichEdit, but I couldn't find a way without using RichEdit, so I'm going to use RichEdit, but it's hard to find samples on the Internet to test whether RichEdit works properly.

Even if you test by changing the variable value such as `bLineSpacingRule` in the `LSpaceA()` and `LSpaceB()` functions in the code below, there is no change in line spacing at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>

#define ID_EDIT 1
#define ID_BUTTON 2

HWND hEdit, hButton;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

char sbuf[900];
void MkBuf()
{
    char sta[300];
    int ii;
 
    strcpy(sbuf,"");
    for(ii=0; ii<6; ii++){ 
        sprintf(sta,"%dth line Test WinApi Test WinApi Test WinApi Test WinApi Test WinApi%c%c", 1+ii,0xD,0xA);
        strcat(sbuf,sta);
    }
}
void LSpaceA()
{
    PARAFORMAT2 pf2;
    pf2.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT2);
    //SendMessage(hEdit, EM_GETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf2);
    pf2.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
    //pf2.dwMask = PFM_SPACEBEFORE;
    //pf2.bLineSpacingRule = 4;
    pf2.dyLineSpacing = 400; // (!)
    SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf2);
}
void LSpaceB(HWND hwnd, int space)
{
    PARAFORMAT2 pf;
    pf.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT2);
    pf.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
    pf.dyLineSpacing = space;
    pf.bLineSpacingRule = 5; // (!)
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf);
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    LoadLibrary("riched20.dll"); // for using rich edit

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = "EditorWindowClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "EditorWindowClass", "Text Editor", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE,
        0, 0, 800, 500, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, hInstance, NULL);

    hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Change Line Spacing", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 510, 150, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, hInstance, NULL);

    MkBuf();
    SetWindowText(hEdit, sbuf);
    LSpaceA();

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON) {
            LSpaceB(hEdit, 20);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This is a slightly modified code obtained from a question on ChatGPT" - you lost me at this point. ChatGPT can't write code.

Comment: So I modified the code.

Comment: Tell us about the "slight modification". You don't develop software (yet) by asking ChatGPT and then tweaking things. Get rid of all the ChatGPT things and show us what you created yourself.

Comment: ChatGPT isn't important, so why are you so obsessed with it?

Comment: Because questions or answers generated by AI are off-topic here according to the site guidelines. See the [help].

Comment: The important thing is to find a way to change the line spacing.
In order to ask a question, I need to create a short sample code, but this time I just used ChatGPT.
AI or not is not important.

Comment: @landcc we are just reluctant to aid anyone that seems that think that the way to do it is to ask ChatGPT or whatever else to create code, then "slighly" modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WinMain()` is creating a standard [Edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls), not a [RichEdit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/rich-edit-controls).  That is why your functions are not working, since the Edit control does not support the [`EM_SETPARAFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setparaformat) message. See [How to Create Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-rich-edit-controls) on MSDN.

You need to change the class name `"EDIT"` to `"RichEdit20A"` instead (ie, use the `RICHEDIT_CLASS` constant defined in `<Richedit.h>`), as you are using `Riched20.dll` (see [Versions of Rich Edit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#versions-of-rich-edit) for more info).

```
//hEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", ...);
hEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, RICHEDIT_CLASS, ...);
```

On a side note: your creation and setup of the `hEdit` and `hButton` control should be moved inside of your `WindowProc()` in a `WM_CREATE` handler.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define ID_EDIT 1
#define ID_BUTTON 2

HWND hEdit, hButton;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

TCHAR sbuf[900];

void MkBuf()
{
    TCHAR sta[300];
    int ii;
 
    _tcscpy(sbuf, _T(""));
    for(ii=0; ii<6; ii++){ 
        _stprintf(sta, _T("%dth line Test WinApi Test WinApi Test WinApi Test WinApi Test WinApi\r\n"), 1+ii);
        _tcscat(sbuf,sta);
    }
}

void LSpaceA()
{
    PARAFORMAT2 pf2;
    pf2.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT2);
    //SendMessage(hEdit, EM_GETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf2);
    pf2.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
    //pf2.dwMask = PFM_SPACEBEFORE;
    //pf2.bLineSpacingRule = 4;
    pf2.dyLineSpacing = 400; // (!)
    SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf2);
}

void LSpaceB(HWND hwnd, int space)
{
    PARAFORMAT2 pf;
    pf.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT2);
    pf.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
    pf.dyLineSpacing = space;
    pf.bLineSpacingRule = 5; // (!)
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM)&pf);
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    LoadLibrary(TEXT("riched20.dll")); // for using rich edit
    // alternatively, load "Msftedit.dll" instead for RichEdit 4.1+...

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("EditorWindowClass");
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("EditorWindowClass"), TEXT("Text Editor"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {

    case WM_CREATE: {
        // alternatively, use MSFTEDIT_CLASS for RichEdit 4.1+...
        hEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, RICHEDIT_CLASS, TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE,
            0, 0, 800, 500, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, NULL, NULL);

        hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Change Line Spacing"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            10, 510, 150, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);

        MkBuf();
        SetWindowText(hEdit, sbuf);
        LSpaceA();

        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON) {
            LSpaceB(hEdit, 20);
        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I did as instructed and finally a change occurred when I pressed the "Change Line Spacing" button - used LSpaceB(hEdit, 90); 
However, among the six lines, only the line spacing after the first line changes.
How do I change all line spacing in Edit-Widget?

Comment: Per the documentation for `EM_SETPARAFORMAT`: "*Sets the paragraph formatting **for the current selection** in a rich edit control.*" If there is text selected, only that text is affected. If there is no selected text, only new text added at the current insertion point is affected.  So, if you want to update the spacing of existing text, you have to select the text first. Use `EM_SETSEL` or `EM_EXSETSEL` for that.

Comment: I really appreciate it.
Finally, I solved a problem that had been inconvenient for several years T.T
It works fine when I put 4 lines under SetWindowText as shown below.
SetWindowText(hEdit, sbuf);
nn = (int)SendMessage(hEdit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETSEL, 0, nn);
LSpaceB(hEdit, 50);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETSEL, 0, 0);

Comment: You don't need `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`. Read the documentation for `EM_SETSEL`: "*If the start is 0 and the end is -1, all the text in the edit control is selected. If the start is -1, any current selection is deselected.*" However, you don't need `EM_SETSEL` at all when first creating the RichEdit. You can send the 1st `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` *before* calling `SetWindowText()` instead of *after*.